# How to set up PHP on HTML contact form?

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I am trying to create a contact form, however, I cannot figure out how to create the PHP to send this filled out form to whichever email I specify and let the user know if success/fail. Can someone please help me with this?

Thank You

```
   <form id="form_1109748" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
<div class="form_description">
    <h2>E-mail Form</h2>
    <p>You can call us at (416) 247-8080 or fill out the form below to get in touch!</p>
</div>                      
    <ul >

            <li id="li_1" >
<label class="description" for="element_1">Name </label>
<span>
    <input id="element_1_1" name= "element_1_1" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="25" value=""/>
    <label>First</label>
</span>
<span>
    <input id="element_1_2" name= "element_1_2" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="25" value=""/>
    <label>Last</label>
</span> 
</li>       <li id="li_2" >
<label class="description" for="element_2">Phone </label>
<span>
    <input id="element_2_1" name="element_2_1" class="element text" size="5" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
    <label for="element_2_1">(###)</label>
</span>
<span>
    <input id="element_2_2" name="element_2_2" class="element text" size="5" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
    <label for="element_2_2">###</label>
</span>
<span>
    <input id="element_2_3" name="element_2_3" class="element text" size="8" maxlength="4" value="" type="text">
    <label for="element_2_3">####</label>
</span>

</li>       <li id="li_3" >
<label class="description" for="element_3">Email </label>
<div>
    <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>       <li id="li_4" >
<label class="description" for="element_4">Car Make </label>
<div>
    <input id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>       <li id="li_5" >
<label class="description" for="element_5">Car Model </label>
<div>
    <input id="element_5" name="element_5" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>       <li id="li_6" >
<label class="description" for="element_6">Message </label>
<div>
    <textarea id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
</div> 
</li>

            <li class="buttons">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="1109748" />

        <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to first learn basics of `PHP`.

Comment: There are about 65936593649 posts with examples alone here on StackOverflow. You are sure none of that helped you? Then why should the 65936593650th example be better?

Comment: You can just use PHP's `mail()` function

Comment: You might also want to consider naming your input tags something more definitive.  If you try to write PHP code to submit this form, you will only confuse your self with which field you are retrieving.

Comment: Please learn some server side programming first..
And for form submission here is a nice tutorial:https://www.123contactform.com/simple-php-contact-form.html

Answer (score -2):

This is an extremely basic version of what you are looking for.  You should learn how to verify the contents of your form fields with PHP before the email is actually sent to avoid any security risks.  But again, this will do what you want.

```
   <?php

/*  If the form has been submitted.  If means that the code between the { and } will only be executed if the statement is true. */
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//change the part inside the quotes to change the mailto address
$mailto = "someaddress@somedomain.com";
$subject = "Your Subject";

//$_POST is the variable that gets all your form information.  It's an array and the array elements(e.g.['element_1_1']) correspond with the names of your form elements.
$message = '
Name: '.$_POST['element_1_1'].'<br>
Phone: '.$_POST['element_2_1'].' '.$_POST['element_2_2'].'-'.$_POST['element_2_3'].'<br>
Email: '.$_POST['element_3'].'<br>
Car Make: '.$_POST['element_4'].'<br>
Car Model: '.$_POST['element_5'].'<br>
Message: '.$_POST['ement_6'];

//We are telling the email script that the message will be made up of HTML
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    //If the mail message was sent, tell the user it was.  If it wasn't, tell the user it was not sent.
    if(mail($mailto, $subject, $_POST['element_6'], $headers)){

        echo "Your email has been sent.";

    } else {

        echo "Could not send your email.";

    }

//The form hasn't been submitted, so display the HTML of the form.
} else { ?>


 <form id="form_1109748" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<div class="form_description">
    <h2>E-mail Form</h2>
    <p>You can call us at (416) 247-8080 or fill out the form below to get in touch!</p>
</div>                      
    <ul >

            <li id="li_1" >
<label class="description" for="element_1">Name </label>
<span>
    <input id="element_1_1" name= "element_1_1" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="25" value=""/>
    <label>First</label>
</span>
<span>
    <input id="element_1_2" name= "element_1_2" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="25" value=""/>
    <label>Last</label>
</span> 
</li>       <li id="li_2" >
<label class="description" for="element_2">Phone </label>
<span>
    <input id="element_2_1" name="element_2_1" class="element text" size="5" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
    <label for="element_2_1">(###)</label>
</span>
<span>
    <input id="element_2_2" name="element_2_2" class="element text" size="5" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
    <label for="element_2_2">###</label>
</span>
<span>
    <input id="element_2_3" name="element_2_3" class="element text" size="8" maxlength="4" value="" type="text">
    <label for="element_2_3">####</label>
</span>

</li>       <li id="li_3" >
<label class="description" for="element_3">Email </label>
<div>
    <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>       <li id="li_4" >
<label class="description" for="element_4">Car Make </label>
<div>
    <input id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>       <li id="li_5" >
<label class="description" for="element_5">Car Model </label>
<div>
    <input id="element_5" name="element_5" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>       <li id="li_6" >
<label class="description" for="element_6">Message </label>
<div>
    <textarea id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
</div> 
</li>

            <li class="buttons">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="1109748" />

        <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</li>
    </ul>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I would like to use that, however I think it is missing the mailto address and also there are multiple text boxes for name/phone but I want it all to go on one line. How will this work?

Comment: The mailto address is represented by $_POST['element_3'] in the mail function.  I have updated the answer to include the full phone number.  Assuming the user enters it correctly, it will appear as (123) 456-7890

Comment: Nice way to create a spam bot if I can set the `$to` address. Also: you're sending HTML emails without sanitizing user input. This code should never see the light of day in production.